# android showing error org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: android, android-studio

when I run the code below by getting an object from my server, I get an error like this

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
at com.halimlab.koneksicrud.TampilBarang.showBarang(TampilBarang.java:89)
at com.halimlab.koneksicrud.TampilBarang.access$000(TampilBarang.java:22)
at com.halimlab.koneksicrud.TampilBarang$1GetBarang.onPostExecute(TampilBarang.java:72)
at com.halimlab.koneksicrud.TampilBarang$1GetBarang.onPostExecute(TampilBarang.java:60)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6739)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:859)
```

I only write this in accordance with the guidelines of my homework, but it all returns an error that I understand

the java code that I entered shows an error leading to one of these lines

```
private void getBarang() {
        class GetBarang extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(TampilBarang.this,"Fetching...","Wait...",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                showBarang(s);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequestParam(konfigurasi.URL_GET_BARANG,id);
                return s;
            }
        }
        GetBarang gb = new GetBarang();
        gb.execute();
    }

    private void showBarang(String json){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(konfigurasi.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
            String nama = c.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_NAMA);
            String kode = c.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_KODE);
            String stok = c.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_STOK);

            editTextName.setText(nama);
            editTextKode.setText(kode);
            editTextStok.setText(stok);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and the php code that refers to it returns a json object like this

```
{
 result: [
  {
   id_barang: "5d336a0b676fb",
   nama_barang: "Nama",
   kode_barang: "kode",
   stok_barang: "123"
  }
 ]
}
```

help me to do it, thank you

Comment: What is on line 89 (`showBarang(TampilBarang.java:89)`)

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the json above in `rh.sendGetRequestParam(konfigurasi.URL_GET_BARANG,id);`?

Comment: line 89 `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);`

Comment: Check that you have a valid json string in `json`

Comment: so where is my code wrong? I don't really understand this

Comment: maybe you are not getting the json object as you expected, try printing the `json` into logcat and make sure that you are getting the correct json

Answer (score 0):

Format of json response which you pasted here is invalid. Json fields should be wrapped in double quotes.

```
{
 "result": [
  {
   "id_barang": "5d336a0b676fb",
   "nama_barang": "Nama",
   "kode_barang": "kode",
   "stok_barang": "123"
  }
 ]
}
```